# log4j doesn't write to file in a Tomcat7 web application on Amazon server

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, amazon-ec2, log4j

I used log4j for logging in my web application which is deployed using Tomcat on Amazon Cloud.
I can see the output of log4j on catalena. But, log file is not being created in the given location "/home/ec2-user/EmailLog/userdetails.log" and no logging is being done.

The same web application is running fine and creating  the file and logging when tried on localhost.

My *log4j.properties* content:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/ec2-user/EmailLog/userdetails.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

And I instantiated the Logger by:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class);
```

Please, suggest modification to make it work on Tomcat-Amazon.

Comment: Did you make sure that the user with which Tomcat runs has sufficient rights to write in /home/ec2-user/EmailLog/? Or, for testing only, set "chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/EmailLog/".

Comment: Hi, I tried the above command. But still my web application coudn't write on to the location.